# SpringBoot - JPA Persisting a @OneToMany relation Duplicate entry '1' for key

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a entity called Home.java and it has a List.
Every home should have a (maybe) different set of Amenities.

And whenver I want to create a new home with its amenities it crashes because of Duplicate entry '1' for key.

This is Home.java:

```
@Entity
property="id")
public class Home  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

private String title;
private String subTitle;
private String shortDescription;
private String description;
private String typeOfPlace;
private Integer amountGuests;
private Boolean dedicatedToGuests;
private Integer bathrooms;
private Boolean bathroomPrivate;

@ElementCollection
private List<Amenities> amenities;

@OneToOne
private Address address;

@ElementCollection
private List<String> pictures;

@OneToOne
private Zone zone;

private Integer maxPeople;

private Double cost;

private Integer rooms;
private Integer beds;

@DefaultValue("false")
private Boolean sponsored;

@DefaultValue("0")
private Double rate;

@DefaultValue("false")
private Boolean published;

private Float lat;

private Float lng;
```

In Amenity.java I don't have a reference to home.

```
@Entity
```

public class Amenities {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String name;
private String imageUrl;
private String icon;

public Amenities() {
}

public Amenities(String name, String imageUrl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}
```

When I persist it works but If I create a new home with some of the same amenities, it crashes.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: it seems you saving the same primary key into database, that why you getting error duplicate entry, attach your full code se we can analyze it

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Yeah we need your code to help you definitively. Is your Home entity annotated with an auto generation strategy for the PK. E.g. @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO).  And ensure that you are not setting the primary key field on Home before persisting a new one.

Comment: Updated the post with the code.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the relation table home_amenities. in Which it forces the amenities id to be unique when it must be duplicated for different home ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

It looks that I had to implement a Many-to-many relation instead.

Thanks everyone!